# How do I use Class Attributes, Arguments and "self." effectively in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am creating a text-based adventure game (as mentioned in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159818/save-and-load-the-state-of-a-role-playing-game-using-pickle) post), and I am stuck on how to use Classes and their attributes, arguments related to classes, and the pre-defined keyword `self.`. I have looked around for how to use them, but to no avail. I will give an example of each, with a question attached to them:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = 15
        self.money = 0

    def display(self, name):
    print("Name:",self.name,"\nHealth:",self.health,"/",self.maxhealth,"\nAttack Damage:",self.attack,"\nMoney:",self.money)
```

Someone from the answers suggested changing `self.name = name` to `self.name = None`, but they didn't explain why or how it would help. If anyone could tell me how to define `self.name` in the correct or most efficient way, please do. I would also like to know how to call it in later functions.

I am confused on how class attributes work (related to previous question), and how you know if they are enabled, and how to call them.

I am also unsure of the arguments that would go into `class Player(#here):`, and how they could be used. I'm not sure if there are any uses to it, but I have seen people do `(object)` and `(Edum #or something like that)` and I don't know what they add, how to call them etc.

```
import time
import random
import sys
import pickle

class Zombie:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 50
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = 5
        self.golddrop = random.randint(5,10)

class Skeleton:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 75
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = random.randint(5,10)
        self.golddrop = random.randint(5,10)


class Friend:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = random.randint(7,10)


class DungeonBoss:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 150
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = random.randint(15, 25)
```

Those are the classes I want in my game. I am wondering whether I can make a class just called "enemies" and then maybe make sub-sets/classes that can then be called from that class (once again, any help with how to call attributes from classes will be much appreciated), so it makes the code a lot cleaner.

Please leave a comment if you are unsure about anything I just said, or if you need some more clarification with the questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're doing well so far, but what you really need here is a short session with a tutorial on classes.  Stack Overflow isn't for such general education.  Just search for "Python class tutorial" and work through the explanations of the concepts.  For guidance on things to ask here, see [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, if you're unsure about using these things, then you shouldn't have so much code to post here.  Write yourself a short game, a few lines at a time: one Player, one Monster, and one battle.  When you get that working, I expect you'll have some nice, focused questions for us.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. When I have the short-game up and running, I'll post again (probably deleting this post) asking whether there is a way of me refining the code and making it more efficient. I have already posted a game that uses classes on codereview.stackexchange.com [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159818/save-and-load-the-state-of-a-role-playing-game-using-pickle), and some of the answers on my classes didn't really make a whole lot of sense, which is why I came here.

Comment: Understood.  However, as you see in the intro tour (which you *have* read now, right?), Stack Overflow is for *specific* programming problems, rather than wider-ranging discussions.  What I suggested is called "incremental programming", and I've found it very useful through my decades of software development and teaching.

Comment: Also, remember that improvements to *working* code go into CodeReview; specific programming problems come here.

Comment: Also, you're quite right in one overall item: make a general class for **Enemy**, and let the specific critters be subclasses of that.  In fact, you can let that class include anything that can interact with the usual attributes (health, name, etc.), and let **Player** be a subclass, as well.

Comment: What would I do to achieve that? Would I do something like `class Enemy(object):` and then make `class dungeon_keeper(Enemy):`? I am not very familiar with inheritance, so this is my best attempt at how I interpret inheritance. @Prune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so quick lesson in Python Classes. First, lets cover self. Self refers to the Object you create for that class. So lets say:

```
zombie1 = Zombie("bob")
```

self in this instance refers to the object "zombie1"

Now, to use attributes of methods. Think of a class as something that encapsulates some generic data. You have that part down it seems already. Now the attributes are those generic data types that the class contains. So for instance, your zombies name, attack, etc. To access them, we simply do as such:

```
zombie1.name
'bob'
zombie1.attack
5
```

So on and so forth. This will give you the data that is attached to those attributes.

Now to make sub classes, you could do something like this.

```
class Enemies(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.maxhealth = 100

class Zombies(Enemies):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = 5
        self.golddrop = random.randint(5, 10)
```

You would assign an object to it like so:

```
zombie2 = Zombie("Mike")
```

The output such as this, will give you the data from the Zombie class and the Enemies Class:

```
zombie2.maxhealth
100
zombie.name
'Mike'
zombie2.attack
5
```

So on and so forth. If you look carefully, you will see that zombie2 has the attribute maxhealth, even though that is initialized and defined under Enemies. Hope this helps some!

Ill leave the enemies class up to you as far as how you wish to create generic enemy data to be used by individual monsters. I just wanted to use maxhealth as an example to show it can pull from the parent class in a sub class.

Response to comment question:

To get a players name, you can go one of two ways, create a method, or ask for it when programming it out. I will show you both ways.

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.gold = None

    def getName(self):
        self.name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        print(self.name)

player1 = Player()
player1.getName()
```

When you call player1.getName() it will ask for their name and store it to the name variable. You can then call there name via:

```
player1.name
'Peter'
```

You could also do:

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.gold = None
```

This way you can call the players name on the object creation such as:

```
player1 = Player(input("Please enter your name here: "))

player1.name
'Peter'
```

This way allows you to specifically code a name, or ask the user for one.

Last edit for the gold bit here:

```
class Player(object):

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.gold = None

def giveGold(self):
    print("Since you are new, 100 gold dubloons have been given to you!")
    self.gold = 100
```

So this allows you to call Player() how ever you wish. You can hardcode a name, or ask for user input. Then run the method giveGold() on the Player() object to grant them 100 gold Dubloons.

```
player1 = Player("Peter")
player1.giveGold()
Since you are new, 100 gold dubloons have been given to you!
player1.gold
100
```

Hope that makes sense. I think I have helped get you started quite well. I will leave the rest of the game making to you :)

Comment: Okay. So, what if I wanted the user to input their own name? Would it be the same concept? I will give an example. `class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.gold = gold

Player.name = input("What do you want your name to be?")
print("Hello there, {0}!".format(Player.name))`. Would that be correct? It works, but I am wondering whether that is the most efficient way of doing it. Thank you for your answer btw.

Comment: Ill will append that to the my answer, if my current answer correctly answers what you ask, please mark the answer with a green check mark to signal it as the accepted answer you were looking for. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I will leave this post overnight and if I get any more answers, I will choose which helped me most, however, if yours is the only one, I will mark yours as the chosen answer. Thank you though.

Comment: Also, I want to add a new function that gets the user's chosen amount of gold, but I don't know how to call it: `class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, gold):
        self.name = name
        self.gold = gold
        
    def get_gold(self):
        user_gold = int(input("""Your local bank, HSBC (Hydra Sasquatch Banking Corporation), is offering you up to
100 gold doubloons for your travels, as you are new to adventuring."""))
        print(user_gold)
user_name = Player(input("What do you want your name to be?"))
print("Hello there, {0}!".format(user_name))`
Any ideas?

Comment: @SavagePotato I have amended my answer to include everything you have asked. I will leave the rest of the game creating up to you. Study this and learn what and why I did what I did and the explanations I have given and you will have no trouble completing your game :)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has helped me out a lot! I will refer back to it throughout my game when I need to, amd hopefully when I have finished the game I won't have any need to refer back to this post :)